# How can I make every page in excel dynamic with each other

Tags: excel, dynamic, static, vlookup

I'm currently creating/organizing what was one excel file with 50 items. 
Within these 50 items, there were roughly 30 things they were linked to.

I split up the 30 items into 3 total pages-- roughly 10 items per page to simplify this question.

I want to know how I can make each page dynamic with one another?

For example, if I have a,b,c, d, ...-y as my "25" items on all 3 pages in column A, how can I make sure that column A stays the same on each page?

If I sort page 2 by column 4 by let's say value, it'll rearrange column A. How can I also make sure that if that happens, that column A in pages 1 and 3 also are in the same order as page 2, while also making sure the values in the columns B through K match up with column A before it was restructured.

Sorry if that's confusing. That's why I'm here.

Comment: Give an example of what you want

Comment: You may want to take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55108566/edit) to clarify things

Comment: @DanielM I gave an example.So if Column A has A-Y on pages 1, 2, and 3, and I want to sort page 2 by column D, it'll rearrange what's in column A. When that happens, how can I also get column A to rearrange in that order on pages 1 and 3?

Comment: Appreciate if you can share a sample file for us to reproduce the case and assist. Without that info (the sample data/fie plus what you had tried and failed), it was pretty hard to see where it whether the suggested solution works/not. Eg : "If I sort page 2 by column 4 by let's say value" > ascending or descending? | "there were roughly 30 things they were linked to" link to outside/inside workbook? is the link generically reproducible with `hyperlink` function? | Hope this won't let you down asking this/next question here/elsewhere. ( :